# Stop function after some time

Tags: javascript, html, background

I want to make a simple background which changes to the colors of the rainbow every 1400 ms, which I did like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/chxoum7z/1/). Here's the code:

```
function onload() {
        var color = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
        var body = document.getElementById('body');
        var i = 0;
        function rainbow() {
            if(i == color.length) {i = 0;};
            body.style.backgroundColor = color[i++];
            setTimeout(rainbow, 1400);
        };
        rainbow();
};

onload();
```

But after running this function for 6049 ms, I want the background to change with intervals of 50ms instead of 1400 ms. How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the interval in another timer like this.

```js
function onload() {
    var color = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
    var body = document.getElementById('body');
    var i = 0;
    var interval = 1400;

    function rainbow() {
        if (i == color.length) {
            i = 0;
        };
        body.style.backgroundColor = color[i++];
        console.log("Interval is: " + interval);
        setTimeout(rainbow, interval);
    };

    var intervalTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        interval = 50;
        clearTimeout(intervalTimer);
    }, 6049);

    rainbow();
};

onload();
```

```html
<body id='body'>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the initial interval is 1400ms, and you want to change after 6049ms, that would mean the change to 50ms would happen between the 5th and 6th color change (0ms, 1400ms, 2800ms, 4200ms, 5600ms, 7000ms). This means we can use the `i` index to set the `setTimeout` interval with `(i < 6 ? 1400 : 50)`.

```js
function onload() {
  var color = ["red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue", "indigo", "violet"];
  var body = document.getElementById('body');
  var i = 0;

  function rainbow() {
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = color[i++ % color.length];
    setTimeout(rainbow, (i < 6 ? 1400 : 50));
  };
  rainbow();
};

onload();
```